# Phinx - database migrations for php app - postgreSQL schema does not work

Tags: php, postgresql, database-migration, phinx

I'm using Phinx for databse migrations.

It's not workig with PostgreSQL schemas in my case (example **test.table**).

```
// create the table
$table = $this->table('test.table');
$table->addColumn('test', 'integer')
      ->create();
```

When i hit `phinx migrate` it causes an arror. Is there any solutions for that?

My error is:

[--> IMAGE ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lf4Fg.png)

The error is: Syntax error or within "."

Does Phinx supports dot notation in the `table`method?

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: Did you specify the pgsql adapter per the documentation? http://docs.phinx.org/en/latest/configuration.html#supported-adapters

Comment: I added img with error [image error]

Comment: @JeremyHarris, Yes i did. It works with public schema, with others not.

Answer (score 3):

I found alternative solution. Before changes in the table, I manualy selected PostgreSQL schema.

```
// changing schema
$this->getAdapter()->setOptions(array_replace($this->getAdapter()->getOptions(), ['schema' => 'your_schema']));

// create the table
$table = $this->table('test_table');
$table->addColumn('test', 'integer')
            ->create();
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you can use dot notation in the table name like that?

```
// create the table
$table = $this->table('test_table');
$table->addColumn('test', 'integer')
    ->create();
```

`test.table` would follow the pattern `databasename.tablename`

Comment: In postgreSQL dot notation follows: `schema.tablename`